# { error: 'not_found', reason: 'deleted', name: 'not_found', status: 404, message: 'deleted' }

Tags: javascript, view, couchdb

I'm building a CouchDB design doc like this:

```
const ddoc={
    "_id":"_design/index2nd",
    "views":{
        "by_id":{
            "map": (function(doc){emit(doc._id, doc);}).toString()
        },
        "by_username":{
            "map": (function(doc){emit(doc.username, doc);}).toString()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm saving the design doc with this:

```
db.put(ddoc).then(()=>{
    ////done!
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log('error: design doc is not saved: ', err)
})
```

The index isn't built until you query it, Therefore I do an empty query to kick off a new build:

```
db.query("index2nd/by_id",{
    limit:0 // don't return any results
}).then(result=>{
    // index was built!
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log('error: index2nd/by_id is not built: ', err)
})

db.query("index2nd/by_username",{
    limit:0//don't return any results
}).then(result=>{
    //index is built
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log('error: index2nd/by_username is not built: ', err)
})
```

However I'm receiving the following error:

> error: index2nd/by_id is not built:  { error: 'not_found',
>     reason: 'deleted',
>     name: 'not_found',
>     status: 404,
>     message: 'deleted' }
>
> error: index2nd/by_username is not built:  { error: 'not_found',
>     reason: 'deleted',
>     name: 'not_found',
>     status: 404,
>     message: 'deleted' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue by using `pouchdb-upsert` plugin. Refer to [this](https://github.com/pouchdb/upsert) and [that](https://pouchdb.com/guides/conflicts.html).

```
const ddoc={
    "_id":"_design/myIndex",
    "views":{
        "by_id":{
            "map": (function (doc){emit(doc._id);}).toString()
        },
        "by_username":{
            "map": (function (doc){emit(doc.username);}).toString()
        }
    }
}

PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-upsert'))

const diffFunc=doc=>{
    return ddoc;//always return the same ddoc
}

db.upsert('_design/myIndex',diffFunc).then(res=>{
    // happily done
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log('error @ upsert: ', err)
})
```